# What does Python's locals() do?

Tags: python

Python's [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) documentation says:

> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Free variables are returned by `locals()` when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks.

1. What are in the current local symbol table exactly?
2. Is the local symbol table guaranteed to be the same as the argument dict if `locals()` is called at the very beginning of a function?

   For example, if we have the following program:

   ```
   def foo(x, y):
       print(locals() == {'x': 1, 'y': 2})
   foo(1, 2)
   ```

   Will it always output `True` no matter what platforms and Python implementations we use?

Comment: @idjaw That question doesn't mention *symbol table* at all.

Comment: @idjaw FYI I want to pass arguments in a function to another function, but I don't want to change the function prototype to `(*args, **kwargs)` for readability. If `locals()` are exactly the same as the argument dict at the beginning of a function, then passing arguments will be very easy.

Comment: Re-reading your question I see the specifics of what you are asking about. I'll delete to remove confusion.

Answer (score 6):

> What are in the current local symbol table exactly?

Well, you can take a look yourself. At the very beginging of your Python, program, here is what the symbol table returned by `locals()` looks like:

```
print(locals())
```

Which outputs:

```
{'__doc__': None, '__spec__': None, '__package__': None, '__builtins__': 
<module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__loader__': 
<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 
'__file__': 'C:\\Users\\$Name$\\Desktop\\script.py'}
```

The symbol table consists of a few "magic variables", and some info about your current Python file. Such as the `__file__` key, which contains the name of your current source file. The description of what locals returns pretty much matches the definition for a symbol table:

> In computer science, a symbol table is a data structure used by a language translator such as a compiler or interpreter, **where each identifier in a program's source code is associated with information relating to its declaration or appearance in the source**. - [Wikipedia: Symbol table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table)

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

---

> Is the local symbol table guaranteed to be the same as the argument dict if locals() is called at the very beginning of a function?

To which the answer would <sup>1</sup>**yes**. Functions have their own scope. And, as hinted at by the name, `locals()` only returns identifiers local to the current scope. So a call to `locals()` inside of a function, could not be changed by the outer scope of a program. eg.

```
>>> var = 10 # global variable
>>> locals()['var'] # var is accessible in the current scope
10
>>> def func():
    print(locals()['var']) # but not in this scope. Python will raise an error


>>> func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    func()
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 2, in func
    print(locals()['var'])
KeyError: 'var'
>>>
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
<sub>Its a little hard to fully understand what your asking in your second question, so I apologize if my answer is not related. But I believe your asking: If I call `locals()` at the beginning of my function, inside of my definition, is the `dict()` returned by locals guaranteed to stay the same?</sub>. If this isn't the case, update your question and I'll try to re-answer.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there will be some builtin names in a function scope other than the parameters. Can you find any Python implementation reference saying a function scope is clean at its very beginning?

Comment: @Cyker Before I answer, lemme make sure were on the same page. **Your asking are there any names in locals at the beginning of your function, besides your parameters**?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking whether there aren't **any** extra names.

Comment: @Cyker Then **no**. Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation that says this because I' currently preoccupied. But the local namespace of a function is going to be clear.