# Assigning specific dictionary values to variables

Tags: python-3.x

I have a series of dictionaries which each contain the same keys but their values are different i.e Age in dictionary 1 = 2, Age in dictionary 2 = 4 etc etc but they are broadly identical in structure.

what I would like to do is to randomly select one of these dictionaries and then assign specific values with the dictionary to variables. i.e python randomly chooses Dictionary 1 and then I then want to fill the dictAge variable with the age value from Dictionary 1.

```
import random

dictList = ['myDict', 'otherDict']

mydict = {
    'age' : 10,
    'other': "dummy data"
    }
.
.
.



randomDict = random.choice(dictList)

dictAge = randomDict['age']

print(dictAge)
```

In the case of the code above what should happen is:

randomDict is assigned a random value from the distList variable (at the top). This sets which dictionary's values will be used going forward.

I next want the dictAge variable to then be assigned the age value from the selected dictionary. In this case (as mydict is was the only dictionary available) it should be assigned the age value of 10.

The error I am getting is:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

I know this is such a common error but my brain can't quite work out what the best solution is.

(Disclaimer: I haven't used python in ages so I know I am doing something really obviously silly but I can't quite work out what to do).

Comment: Hint: `dictList` contains strings instead of dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are not actually using the definition of your dicts.

This is because `dictList` is comprised of strings: `['myDict', 'otherDict']`.

So, when doing `randomDict = random.choice(dictList)`, `randomDict` will either be the **string** `'myDict'`, or the **string** `'otherDict'`.

Then you are doing `randomDict['age']`, which means you are trying to slice a string, with a string. As the error suggests, this can't be done and indices can only be ints.

---

What you want to do, is move the definition of the `dictList` to be **after** the definitions of your dicts, and include references to the dicts themselves, not strings. Something like:

```py
mydict = {
    'age' : 10,
    'other': "dummy data"
    }
.
.
.
dictList = [myDict, otherDict]
```

Comment: Sorry for taking ages to reply - I was moving house! Thanks for this pointer, I think I have got something working now. I definitely hadn't given enough consideration to the order in which I was declaring stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In the following piece of code:

```
dictAge = randomDict['age']
```

You are trying to index the name of dictionary variable (a string) returned by `random.choice` function.

To make it work you would need to do it using [`locals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796264/what-does-pythons-locals-do):

```
locals()[randomDict]['age']
```

or rather correct the `dictList` to contain the dictionaries instead of their names:

```
dictList = [myDict, otherDict]
```

In the latter case please note that `myDict` and `otherDict` should be declared before `dictList`.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something remarkably straightforward - thanks for pointing this out and apologies for taking ages to reply.

Comment: If you find it useful please mark the answer as accepted. You can also separately upvote it.